# Use RPI instead of Arduino

Tags: camera

I am starting a project where I need to take a time-lapse using the RPI Camera V2, each image should be processed slightly, run some algorithms (main part of project) and then save the image to SD card. I have some experience with Arduino and my first idea was to just use an Arduino. But it turns out that my memory requirements (about 100 Mb) are far to big to use any Arduino, but RPI has enough memory to run my algorithms. So I have realized that I need to use an RPI.

This however creates another issue. The camera should take an picture with the interval of 0.5 to 15s as calculated by the algorithm. Between that, it must sleep as deep as possible to save power as this whole thing will be battery powered. Also the battery can die at any time.

The pros of using Arduino is:

- No long startup time
- No problem if power is lost and it dies
- Good deep sleep

The downside of RPI:

- Takes long time to boot
- Power loss can cause file system corruption (have already experienced that)
- No good deep sleep

It seem like I have two bad options. Arduino wont work at all, and the raspberry pi will just eat through the battery too quickly.

Is it possible to use an RPI to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi is not suitable for such start/stop operations requiring battery power.